# 360° panorama libraries for ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, panoramas

Are there any libraries or classes out there to show a 360 degree panorama on the `iPhone`?

I found this here: http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/
but it's not up to date and only for old versions of ios.

I'm thankfull for any link that helps me to create a 360 degree panorama view on ios.

Comment: It's not only for old versions of ios. It's easy to launch it under ios 4. what are the problems concerning ios 4 capability  do you have?

Comment: Looks like they have added support for iOS 5 (at least they have tested in it)

Comment: @choise: Hi! what library(360 degree Panaroma) have you used in Xcode iOS development. Or you did webApp for safari. Can you share your experience with me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NavnathMemane i used KRPano inside a ios application using a uiwebview. worked fine

Comment: how to replace the image in the queues? eg, change area image in the image, for example, replace new color in a car within the 360 view

Comment: I couldn't find something that fits my needs and ended up developing one myself. It can be found [here](https://github.com/scihant/CTPanoramaView).

Comment: you should add this as an answer @CihanTek. This looks great

Comment: @choise I couldn't because it's a closed topic :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've recently found [KRPano](http://krpano.com/iphone/) and since it's not listed here..

Comment: poorly its impossible to view the demo in iphone simulator (local) http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/80699/Bildschirmfoto%202010-10-25%20um%2016.03.12.png

Comment: You need a license as said here: http://krpano.com/iphone/#howtouseit

Comment: shure, but first i would like to try before i buy ;)

Comment: i ended up using this. works the way i want. even if its a bit tricky

Comment: does KRPano worked in UIWebView ? can you tell us how ?

Comment: yes, used it with success in an application. looks pretty good with some tweaking.

Answer (score 17):

Check this open source UIView subclass to make awesome interactive 360-180 degrees panorama from 6 images, one for each face of a cube.In the link you can check the example

[PanoramaViewer](http://javieralog.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/japanoview-open-source-panorama-viewer.html)

Comment: do you know how to take these 6 images by iphone? please help...

Answer (score 5):

The VR5 pano viewer at http://www.vrhabitat.com/#vr5 should do what you need.

When you download it, you can test it out by importing the vr5_script folder into your Xcode project, making sure to check the "Create folder references for any added folders" option, then load it into the webview:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[
     [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"
     inDirectory:@"vr5_script"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

I just gave it a try and it seems to work quite well. Please consider donating to the author if you use it for commercial use (I am not affiliated with the author).

Comment: yeah i tryed that, but its not very smooth, without smooth scrolling and all of that. also it does work in mobile safari, but in a uiwebview there are some problems with multitouch actions

Answer (score 4):

Apple's "HTML5" gallery includes 360° panorama implemented using proprietary CSS and JS extensions:

http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/vr/

Works very well in all Apple browsers, including Mobile Safari, but it's *designed* **not** to work in other browsers.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "designed not to" which implies they put effort into breaking it in Firefox, or "not designed to" which implies they just didn't bother making it work?

Comment: Thanks, I've just looking at this for Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 4):

The one found here: http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/ is already updated for iOS 5.1. You can download the example and use the library offline and online.

Comment: is there any way to implement a gyroscope movement with this?

Comment: May Be Try SceneKit , Add a Scene and Put Any HDRI Photo as a Background it's working much better those days after iOS 10 specially with AR iOS 11

Answer (score 2):

I am currently building a similar system, and had as much luck as you did with this.  Ended up using UIScrollView to provide a panorama-like effect, even though I was not able to wrap it around entirely successfully.  I used the WWDC video from session 104 (2010) to help me optimize large image loading.

OpenGL ES may be a more elegant solution if you have the time/skill (I've only dabbled in OpenGL), but I certainly had no luck finding a panorama library anywhere (except for the deprecated panoramagl).  It's certainly a doozy.

Comment: i have not the opengl es skills ;) as always, deadline is coming fast.  i also tried using a scrollview but ended up with no good solution

Comment: Wish you good luck buddy! Deadlines suck!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the correct answer here. I used this code and works like a charm for me. Hope will help for you as well. 
[Here](http://javieralog.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/japanoview-open-source-panorama-viewer.html)