# Extract a rotatedRect area - iOS version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, opencv

Hi I've been trying to get an iOS solution for an OpenCV problem described -> [This problem here.](http://answers.opencv.org/question/497/extract-a-rotatedrect-area/). In short:

> Can someone explain to me how you would extract a RotatedRect to a
>   submatrix image. Basically, using something like cvSetImageROI to
>   extract the inverted rectangular area from the image?

Does anyone know how I should begin?

Comment: Well, the link you provided has solutions posted to it. If what your are asking is "Does anyone have code to implement a ..... as described in this openCV question, that might help you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763978/360-panorama-librarys-for-ios) has a bunch of suggestions for tools, libraries, apps for panorama making on iPhone.