# Creating a 360 photo experience on iOS mobile device

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, panoramas, 360-panorama

I am interested in VR and trying to get a bit more information. I want to create a similar experience on iOS where I can take a 360 image and be able to view it on a iOS device by tilting the phone around and using the devices gyroscope, as I tilt the phone around it will pan around the 360 image (like on google street view where you can use the tilt gesture).

And something similar to this app: http://bubb.li/

Can anybody give a brief overview how this would be do-able, any sources that could help me achieve this, API's etc...?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [360° panorama libraries for ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763978/360-panorama-libraries-for-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Two options here: You can use a dedicated device to capture the image for you, or you can write some code to stitch together multiple images taken from the iOS device as you move it around a standing point.

I've used [the Ricoh Theta](https://theta360.com/en/) for this (no affiliation). They have a 360 viewer in the SDK for mapping 360 images to a sphere that works exactly as you've asked.

Comment: thanks for this! I'll download and have a play around. As much as taking the photo, do you also have any knowledge on how these photos could be viewed via tilting/panning the device and using the gyroscope within the device. I know it involves the coreMotion framework but I just need a bit more of a helping hand! thanks

Comment: There is a viewer in the SDK that does all those things

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look then

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've figured out how to create 360 photospheres, you can use Unity and Unreal, and probably development platforms to create navigation between the locations you captured.

Here is a tutorial that looks pretty detailed for doing this in Unity:
https://tutorialsforvr.com/creating-virtual-tour-app-in-vr-using-unity/

One pro of doing this in something like Unity or Unreal is once you have navigation between multiple photo spheres working it's fairly easy to add animation or other interactive elements. I've seen interactive stories done with 360 video using this method.

(I see that the question is from a fairly long time ago, but it was one of the top results when I looked for this same topic)